# What is the tool for address checksum?

Tags: addresses, checksum

I have an error from web3:

`Unhandled rejection Error: Given address "0x" is not a valid Ethereum address.`

My question is if is there any tool that can fix my address (add checksum).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pass an illegal address, without any trailing zeros. Are you trying to send to the zero address (0x0) ?

Comment: No I found out that etherscan.io is formatting address in correct form with checksum, but I still have warning from web3.

Comment: Here is an online tool for you https://tokenmarket.net/ethereum-address-validator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you prefer a simple web version, check out [EthSum](https://ethsum.netlify.com):

[image: EthSum Screen Capture]

Disclaimer: I'm the author, it's an [open source tool](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/ethsum).

Comment: Top notch tool, I use it all the time. But please update after an address has been checksummed to say, "this address has been checksummed" rather than "this address had already been checksummed." It was very confusing for a newbie like me.

Comment: Thanks Nic, happy that you like it! Could you clarify your issue, please? There's no "had already been checksummed" message, only "address is already checksummed" when the input address is already in the correct form. Would you rather want to see "address has been checksummed" all the time?

Answer (score 13):

With web3 you can do:

`web3.toChecksumAddress('INSERT ADDRESS HERE')`

It will return the address with checksum

Comment: In a new version of web3 you have to use web3.utils.toChecksumAddress

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

Replcae your address in the following url of etherscan https://etherscan.io/address/{address} like this:

you want the checksum for address `0x0fd60495d705f4fb86e1b36be396757689fbe8b3` so you need to call https://etherscan.io/address/0x0fd60495d705f4fb86e1b36be396757689fbe8b3 then copy the address with valid checksum `0x0Fd60495d705F4Fb86e1b36Be396757689FbE8B3` on the loaded page.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These are the functions you're looking for: [specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md#specification) of the corresponding EIP and the [implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md#implementation).

Comment: Is there an interactive online version anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

ethers.js also does the job. It's more lightweight than web3.js.

```js
// Injects the checksum (via upper-casing specific letters)
ethers.utils.getAddress("0x8ba1f109551bd432803012645ac136ddd64dba72");
// '0x8ba1f109551bD432803012645Ac136ddd64DBA72'
```

[ethers Docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/address/#utils-getAddress)

Answer (score 1):

1. With `ethers@v5`

```
 ethers.utils.isAddress(YOUR_ADDRESS)
```

2. With `ethers@v6`

```
 ethers.isAddress(YOUR_ADDRESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @3lLobo answer above on utlizing ethers.js:

ethers.js is moved from v5 to v6. So many things from v5 are no longer supported in v6 including utils. https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/

https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/address/#isAddress

Before:

```
ethers.utils.getAddress();
```

After:

```
ethers.getAddress();
```